# Kafka Mirror Maker 2.0 Consumer Group Replication

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I was trying out the new Mirror Maker 2.0 with Kafka version 2.5

According to [this wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0), the Mirror Maker can replicate groups as well.

**Questions:**

- Does Mirror Maker 2.0 replicate the consumer group as well? (By saying replicating consumer group, I mean does it replicates group's lag information?)
- If so, what do we need to set in properties to get the same?

Answer (score 0):

> Does Mirror Maker 2.0 replicate the consumer group as well? (By saying
> replicating consumer group, I mean does it replicates group's lag
> information?)

Yes it is.

> If so, what do we need to set in properties to get the same?

As you are using kafka version 2.5, in which there was a [bug for offset syncing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-545%3A+support+automated+consumer+offset+sync+across+clusters+in+MM+2.0) which has been fixed in version 2.7. You can use kafka version 2.7 and above, working fine on that.